# Basis for alternating k-linear functions on V

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

In Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* pg 31-32, an alternating k-linear function $f$on a vector space V, i.e. $f\in A_k(V)$ is expressed in its basis as $$f = \sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$$ where $I$ is the multi-index notation $I=(i_1,...,i_k)$ with $i_1<...<i_k$.  We write $e_I$ for $(e_{i_1},...,e_{i_k})$ and $\alpha^I$ for $\alpha^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge\alpha^{i_k}$.

The author claimed that  this expression is true and used it to prove that $\alpha^I$ span $A_k(V)$. However, this seems like a circular argument to me. What if there is actually another linearly independent basis $g$ that is not accounted for? In other words, we have $g\neq \sum c_I \alpha^I$ where $g\in A_k(V)$ and $c_I$ are constants.

Comment: From what I see in the text, in Proposition 3.29 he proves that every $f\in A_k(V)$ is of the form you wrote -- it was not assumed. To prove it, he showed that if $g = \sum f(e_I) \alpha^I$, then $g(e_J) = f(e_J)$ for all $J$. Since $f$ and $g$ are $k$-linear alternating functions on $V$, they are completely determined by their values on all the $e_J$. This allows him to deduce $f = g$.